# Bottom of bookmark covered by dock after macbook is upgraded to Mojave

Tags: mojave, dock

On my macbook, the dock is always standing at the bottom, since I never want to use the option "automatically hide and show".  On High Sierra, the dock's presence would not interfere the display of the bookmark. Even if there are a long list of entries in the bookmark, it would not be blocked by the dock. However, after my macbook was upgraded to Mojave last night, the dock would block the bottom entries of the long bookmark list. Wondering if there is any fix for this...

Screenshot with dock "auto hide and show" disabled:
[image: Screenshot with dock "auto hide and show" disabled]

Screenshot with dock "auto hide and show" enabled
[image: Screenshot with dock "auto hide and show" enabled]

**Update:**
*After a few days, without anything being done, suddenly the problem disappeared. Please look at the following screenshot. I don't know why, but it is good to see the bottom of the bookmarks no longer being blocked by the dock.*
[image: bookmarks no longer blocked by the dock]

Comment: Which bookmarks are you referring to? Safari bookmarks? From the sidebar or menu? Perhaps you could add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @grg I am referring to the bookmarks in Google Chrome. Will try to add a screenshot later.

Comment: @grg Also, it is from bookmarks bar, not from the menu. Not sure if it could be counted as a sidebar, since it is not on the lefthand side or the righthand side. It is located on top of the browser, just below the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

You might try moving the dock to either the left or right sides of the screen, rather than the bottom: System Preferences > Dock > Position on screen.

In the same Preference Pane, the size of the Dock can also be adjusted with the topmost "Size" slider.

(This is in macOS Mojave; might be different in other versions)

Comment: But back when my macbook was installed with High Sierra, the dock was in the same position (bottom), and it doesn't block the long bookmark list at all.  The bottom is my preferred position for the dock, and I don't want to change that.  :(

Comment: Just curious if this is a regression from High Sierra. Anyone else with Mojave has the same problem?

Comment: It's been awhile since I migrated from High Sierra, but I think it was the same in that OS.

Comment: What is the same in High Sierra and Mojave, long bookmarks blocked by the dock or not? I clearly remember it was not blocked by the dock in High Sierra. I don't use the "auto hide and show" for the dock, either, both in High Sierra and Mojave.

Comment: I meant the Preference Pane controls for the Dock appear to be the same in Mojave as they were in High Sierra.